# React Native How to pass data from javascript to java android

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I followed the tutorial on this site:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html

Now I want to have a function in my javascript code like this:

```
greetingFunction(){

     return "HELLO, WORLD";
}
```

I want to pass the string "HELLO, WORLD" to my java android code and set the screen to display that string.

How can I do this?

Comment: want to do exactly reverse..want to pass data from java android to javascript..

Answer (score 2):

You should create a [custom module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) to call custom native methods in Java where you can pass the data you need.

For instance if your custom native module implements the following method:

```java
@ReactMethod
public void myMethod(String message) {
  // Here we show a toast message
  Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Then you can call that method from JavaScript:

```
NativeModules.MyCustomModule.myMethod("HELLO WORLD");
```

Be sure to properly follow all steps described in the doc above to properly register your custom module.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the doc, and when i run the app it says it cant find the module "./ToastAndroid", which is what i returned in getName(). How many javascript files did you have after you did this? 2? I want to see if i did this correctly
And also, that doc tells you how to pass data/call java function in javascript, but I also want to be able to pass data back from the javascript to the java android. How would one accomplish such a task?

Comment: Did you properly register your module: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#register-the-module ?